# How to Automate the installation of Chef Agent in Nodes or Servers

Tags: cloud, chef-infra

We are planning to provide cluster environment to our customers in cloud. We are planning to automate it Using Chef. Now there is doubt with Chef-client agent. When installing chef agent, we need to download the chef agent manually in each nodes. I have to automate the process that when customer needs a cluster environment, Chef-client agent should be installed automatically without any manual intervention. Is there any way to do that within the scope of Chef or we need to do it using Programming?

Comment: Not sure, what you mean. You can include chef in your image. This question is very broad..

Comment: When you bootstrap a node using Chef, it will attempt to download the Chef-client (assuming it has access to the Chef website)

Comment: Yes, please, specify the method you plan to use to boot the instances. AWS AutoScaling maybe?

Comment: A lot of people do not realise that "knife bootstrap" will install chef-client, if it's not already present. Various cloud plugins exist for knife that will additionally provision servers. Finally cloud-init (offered by manyy clouds) can also install chef client, see: http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/examples.html#install-and-run-chef-recipes

Answer (score 0):

You can bake Chef + a client config + the validator key into your disk image (AMI, etc). The hard part becomes assigning the run list for each node. This is usually handled by starting chef-client the first time via the provisioning system (eg. cloud-init on EC2) with the `-j` command line option and a JSON file with the desired run list derived from information from the cloud backplane.

Comment: I wouldn't condone baking keys into server images. Not only has it security considerations, it assumes the image will only be used to connect to a single chef server/org...

Comment: It's the simplest option with the validator key. Another option is to grab it from an IAM-protected S3 bucket but custom AMIs live on S3 so it's not really any different in terms of at-rest security in the end.

Comment: I would prefer that credentials be supplied at deploy time. (The credentials to access Chef server, or the creds used to access the S3 bucket containing that key). When baked into the image, you've hardcoded that image to a single chef server and lost control over who can connect to it. Finally rotating keys requires a rebuild of the dependent images.